# Pipe script into deno run

Tags: deno

I have an executable that generates javascript that I'd like to pipe into `deno run`, however the `run` subcommand only seems to take a script path as an argument, and doesn't support the usual convention of `-` to read from stdin.

Workarounds that I'm aware of but not satisfied with:

- Save script in a temporary file, and feed it into `deno run`
- Pipe script into `deno repl` (this prints a bunch of repl garbage along with the desired script output)
- Use `deno eval` (my generated javascript is large... feels icky to provide as a command line argument)

Comment: It will land in Deno 1.1 https://github.com/denoland/deno/pull/6266/files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now you can use the following syntax:

```
cat file.js | deno run -
```

If you need permissions:

```
cat file.js | deno run --allow-all -
```